# Letters overlapping when setting alpha using color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Below I have 2 `div` tags with the same text. One sets the font transparency using `color` , and the other using `opacity`.

In the 2nd tag, I can see the desired result, but in the first one, I see some letters overlapping with each other and that creates a translucent/opaque effect.

Could anyone explain why this font rendering occurs?

**EDIT: The issue occurs in Google Chrome**

```css
body{ font-family: Lobster; background: black; }
div{ font-size: 100px; }
div:hover{ color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.alpha{ color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3); }
.opac{ color: #fff; opacity: .3; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="alpha">Toshio Bando</div>
<div class="opac">Toshio Bando</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In chrome this behaviour is handled correctly. As per the CSS [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#propdef-opacity) the **opacity property** should be treated as a **post-processing** operation. **RGBA** on the other hand is intended to **render all individual components** separately off-screen, blending them together, and then rendering to the DOM with element properties such as opacity applied in post.

However, this issue will be experienced on both elements when viewing in Firefox due to poor implementation of the CSS specification:

[image]

Correct rendering within Chrome:

[image]

Code for reproducing the issue cross-browser:

```css
body{ font-family: Lobster; background: black; }
div{ font-size: 100px; }

.alpha:hover{ color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); }
.alpha{ color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3); }

.opac:hover{ color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.opac{ color: #fff; opacity: .3; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="alpha">Toshio Bando</div>
<div class="opac">Toshio Bando</div>
```

Comment: I had the same thought, but I'm looking for a more technical answer. :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava updated my answer to reflect what is mentioned in the CSS specification.

Answer (score 1):

What you should know about font's that will answer your question that each letter is a single object, so if you give the opacity on the div it self the whole div will be transparent, but if you give it for the font each letter will be transparent so when the letters overlap the transparency decrease, that's why you can see darker places in the sentence.

You can see when the letters are not overlap it behave the same, but when it overlap darker places appears.

```css
body{ font-family: Lobster; background: black; }
div{ font-size: 100px; }

.alpha:hover{ color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1); }
.alpha{ color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3); }

.opac:hover{ color: #fff; opacity: 1; }
.opac{ color: #fff; opacity: .3; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="alpha">IIII Basil</div>
<div class="opac">IIII Basil</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the typeface, that design puts one letter over another and in the parts that intersect, it is seen in another color because the background color changes for the letter that is hover, if you want to avoid that, choose a typeface that does not cross each other.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't the same effect occur with opacity?

Comment: What browser are you testing with? I'm using Chrome and I see the 2 of them the same

Comment: Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88. Seems to be the latest